# Elasticsearch: Dynamic change of node configuration settings

Tags: elasticsearch

I know there is an API to change cluster wide settings in a transient and persistent way. But I need to add a tag on a single node without restarting the node. To be more precise, in addition to introducing a new tag  `node.storage_type = value` in `elasticsearch.yaml`, I want to add it through the REST API. Otherwise, the restart of the cluster node by node takes too long.

The nodes info API is a read-only API and does not allow PUT requests. So, does anbody know any way how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is nothing to update Node Settings using the REST API (except Cluster Settings and Index Settings). There was a plugin to [reload config files](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-reloadsettings), but it looks unmaintained and installing this plugin would require a node restart.

There are some things you can do speed node restart though:

```
# Disable allocation during restart
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "none"
    }
}

# Synced flush
POST /_flush/synced
```